# mysqli cannot call stored procedure

Tags: mysqli, procedure

Procedure

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists db1.test;
create procedure db1.test()
deterministic
begin
    select * from table1;
end$$
delimiter ;
```

php code:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','username','passwd','db1');
$query1 = 'select * from table1';
$query2 = 'call test()';
```

Then `$conn->query($query1)` works while `$conn->query($query2)` returns bool(false).
But in mysql, both query1 and query2 work.

What did I miss here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if it's not the syntax, it could be permissions. Did you grant execute privileges to the user for this database?

Edit:

Here's the SQL to do this:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON `db1` . * TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

(Even if a user has all the permissions required to do the SQL inside the stored procedure as individual queries, you'd still need the EXECUTE privilege to actually call the procedure.)

Comment: Not sure about this and I'll look into it! Thanks for the tips.    EDIT: it works! Permission is the problem here :)

Comment: Great! You got it working even before I could add the details :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the procedure is being created? Both MySQL Workbench and phpMyAdmin are telling me there's a syntax error in select * from table; --- probably because table is a reserved word? This worked in MySQL Workbench:

```
USE `db1`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `test`;
DELIMITER $$
USE `db1`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `db1`.`test` ()
BEGIN
    select * from `table`;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Note the addition of backticks to table. With that change on my system, $query2 succeeds but $query1 fails (with or without the change to the procedure of course)

Comment: i'm sorry but table is just an alias here. But within mysql, both query1 and query2 work.

Comment: I just went back and added the DETERMINISTIC keyword; still works.