# Calling dynamic stored procedure doesn't return the correct values

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    
    $query = "CALL AV2GetColsData(?, ?);";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $inType, $inCode);
    $inType = $type;
    $inCode = '\'' . $code . '\'';
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($sqlResult);
    $stmt->fetch();
    echo var_dump($sqlResult);
?>
```

The `AV2GetColsData(type, code)`

goes like that:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=myDBp@localhost PROCEDURE AV2GetColsData(IN type VARCHAR(258) CHARSET utf8, IN code VARCHAR(32) CHARSET utf8)
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    SET @inner_sql = AV2GetMyColumns(type);
    SET @sql_stmt = CONCAT('SELECT ', @inner_sql, ' FROM myTable WHERE reference = ', code, ';');
Prepare stmt FROM @sql_stmt;  
EXECUTE stmt;  
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and the `AV2GetMyColumns(type)`

goes like that:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=myDB@localhost FUNCTION AV2GetMyColumns(type VARCHAR(258) CHARSET utf8) RETURNS varchar(4096) CHARSET utf8
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE rownum INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE columns_string VARCHAR(4096) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE col_string VARCHAR(512);
  SET rownum = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM av2_column_names);
  SET columns_string = '';
  WHILE counter <= rownum DO
    SET col_string = (
      SELECT column_name
      FROM av2_column_names 
      WHERE 
        column_id = counter AND 
        column_type = type AND
        displayed != 0
    );
    IF col_string IS NULL
        THEN
        SET col_string = '';
    END IF;
    IF columns_string = '' THEN
        SET columns_string = col_string;
    ELSE
        IF NOT (col_string = '')
        THEN
            SET columns_string = CONCAT(CONCAT(columns_string, ', '), col_string);
        END IF;
    END IF;
    SET counter = counter + 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN columns_string;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

If I bind the following parameters in the `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $inType, $inCode);`

`$inType = 'overall;'`

`$inCode = '\'' . '0931500612CB' . '\'';`

I get the result NULL from .

If I put the following values in the phpMyAdmin

`type = overall`

`code = 0931500612CB;`

(no quotes for 0931500612CB)
for executing AV2GetColsData
I get the following error:

```
The following query has failed: "SET @p0='overall'; SET @p1='0931500612CB'; CALL `AV2GetColsData`(@p0, @p1); "

MySQL said: #1054 - Unknown column '0931500612CB' in 'where clause'
```

This is why I have this code: `$inCode = '\'' . $code . '\'';`

If I have this code `$inCode = $code;`

I get
`mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown column '0931500612CB' in 'where clause' in extract-data-from-db.php`

If I put the following values in the phpMyAdmin

`type = overall`

`code = '0931500612CB'`

(mind the single quotes around 0931500612CB) it executes correctly.
`Your SQL query has been executed successfully. 1 row affected by the last statement inside the procedure. SET @p0='overall'; SET @p1='\'0931500612CB\''; CALL AV2GetColsData(@p0, @p1);`

The problem is that even this query doesn't work:

```
$sqlQueryColLabels = "SELECT column_name, column_label FROM av2_column_names WHERE (column_type = ?) AND (`displayed` = 1);";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $sqlQueryColLabels );
$stmt->bind_param('s', $inType);
$inType = $type;
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($sqlResult);
$stmt->fetch();
echo '</br></br>';
echo var_dump($sqlResult);
```

Here too the result is NULL.

All things work in simple mysql.

I also tried PDO. It works on a simple SELECT but it can't call the procedure

```
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB", "my_user", "my_password");
$query = $pdo->prepare("CALL AV2GetColsData(?, ?);");
$query->execute(array($inType, $inCode));
$results = $query->fetchAll();
var_dump($results);
```

Here I also get NULL.

What am I doing wrong?

I went through these posts (and lots more):

[PHP MySQLi Prepare Statement Failing to return rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978423/php-mysqli-prepare-statement-failing-to-return-rows)
[PHP mysqli prepare statement not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769966/php-mysqli-prepare-statement-not-working)
[Mysqli query no result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42602615/mysqli-query-no-result)
[mysqli cannot call stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596930/mysqli-cannot-call-stored-procedure)

Comment: Did you print the query and run it manually in the database?

Comment: It looks like you managed to create an SQL vulnerability even when using prepared statements.

Comment: Are you sure the SP executed correctly? Can you fetch the next result?

Comment: @ShehrozAltaf Not more than that, that I inserted the strings into placeholders and then run in phpMyAdmin.  I don't know how to get the prepared query var_dumped.

Comment: @Dharman SP does its work when executing with normal mysql. But right now after the calling SP I even cannot kill the connection:
        $thread = $mysqli->thread_id;
        $mysqli->kill($thread);
        $mysqli->close();

Comment: kill the connection? You are trying to kill the thread. Are you saying that MySQL is stuck continuously processing the SP? Also, I don't know if you can kill a thread from PHP if the connection is busy. Try fetching the remaining result set and see if you get an error.

Comment: For a test try to execute the SP from PHP without binding (it's not helpful here much because the SP is open to SQL injection anyway. Also try the textual protocol rather than prepared statement. Sometimes MySQL has bugs when using the binary one with SP.

Comment: @Dharman With this: $sqlQuery = "CALL AV2GetColsData('overall', '\'0931500612CB\'');";
  $sqlQueryColDataProc = $mysqli->prepare( $sqlQuery ); 
  $sqlQueryColDataProc->execute();
  $sqlQueryColDataProc->bind_result($sqlResult);
  $sqlQueryColDataProc->fetch();
        echo '</br></br>';
  echo var_dump($sqlResult);
I get NULL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246813/discussion-between-dharman-and-igor-beuermann).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Dharman I found the solution. I am not aware of all the nitty-gritties of PHP to explain why (far from that). But at the end PDO did the magic

```
<?php
    $pdo=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world;charset=utf8", "my_user", "my_password");
    $query = $pdo->prepare("CALL AV2GetColsData(?, ?);");
    $inType = $type;
    $inCode = '\'' . $code . '\'';
    $query->execute(array($inType, $inCode));
    $results= $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($results);
    echo '</br></br>';
?>
```

Still, the question is why the second string has to be between additional escaped quotes. The first string ($type) is always just letters (like 'overall'), while the second ($code) always starts with 0 and it can or not end with letters (like '0931500612CB' or '0931480526').

But my boss is not interested in this. And therefore I don't have time for a research. But if someone can explain: you are kindly invited.

Comment: The second string has to be in quotes, because you are dynamically building an SQL inside your SP. A string needs to be in quotes. You are injecting it as part of SQL.

Comment: @Dharman The first string never has this status of injecting?

Comment: I don't think you are using the first string to build an SQL anywhere. You are only using it as a value. Whereas the second one is used to concatenate an SQL.